# difference between these functions

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between these 3 functions? What use is the new operator in the second function? Why should one use the first function over the third function?

**First**

```
var person = function(name){
    this.name = alert(name);
};

var k = new person('kkkk');
var j = new person('jjjj');
```

**Second**

```
var person2 = function(name){
    person2.name = alert(name);
};

var k2 = new person2('kkkk2');
var j2 = new person2('jjjj2');
```

**Third**

```
var person3 = function(name){
    person3.name = alert(name);

};

var k3 = person3('kkkk3');
var j3 = person3('jjjj3');
```

Comment: `new` is used to perform constructor invocations (as opposed to "regualar" (function) invocations). Inside the constructor, you want to be using `this` in order to add stuff to the newly created instance.

Answer (score 5):

The `alert` actually makes it pretty hard to examine the effects, so in my explanations, I'll assume `alert(name)` is actually `name`. (`alert` returns `undefined`, not its input)

The first one makes a function that you could use like a class. You then used it with `new` and made two objects, `k` and `j`. The `this` made it so you could access the names such that `k.name === 'kkkk'` and `j.name === 'jjjj'`.

The second one is similar to the first one, but `k2.name` and `j2.name` are `undefined`. You can access `person2.name`, but that's only equal to the name of the last time you instantiated it; thus, `person2.name === 'jjjj2'`.

The third one is similar to the second one, but doesn't abuse `new`. `k3` and `j3` are `undefined`, and you will get an error if you try to access `k3.name` and `j3.name`. Again, you will be able to access the value last passed to `person3` with `person3.name`.

Comment: I run the second and third example in console (after replacing alert(name) with name). Then i run console.log(person2.name) and console.log(person3.name). Both output empty string. Isn't that contradicting part of your otherwise great answer? Also, what do you mean by "does not abuse name", please?

Comment: @clime: Oh, I forgot that `name` on functions was used for something else. If you renamed `name` to `name2` then it should work as I described. To answer your other question, that's a typo; "does not abuse `name`" should be "does not abuse `new`".

Comment: Yes, it works as you described after replacing person3.name with person3.name2. Is name2 something like a static property here?

Comment: @clime: Yeah, you could say that.

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third function will not assign anything to `person2.name` and `person3.name`. So technically only your first function is valid that's why it should be used.

There is a very important concept in javascript called `context`. A context can be thought of as an object. `this` keyword refers to the context in which a function is executing.

You can create a new property in current context with the help of `this`. For example:

```
var person = function(name) {
    this.name = name; // this can be accessed externally, just like public properties
    var _name = name; // this can be accessed only within the function, just like a private property
    __name = name; // if a property is not properly initialized with a 'var' or 'this', it becomes part of 'window' object, hence you can access it from anywhere using 'window.__name'
}
```

You can create a new context using `new` keyword:

```
var k = new person2('kkkk2'); // this will create a new context, create a property name in it and assign it value passed to function.
var j = new person('jjjj'); // this will create another context
```

You can always access different contexts and their properties:

```
alert(k.name); // this will show 'kkkk2'
alert(j.name); // this will show 'jjjj'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one declares a function, `person()`, that is (presumably) intended to be used as an object constructor - kind of the closest JavaScript comes to having classes. That means if you call it with `new person()` JS will create a new instance of a `person` object, and within the constructor `this` refers to that new instance so `this.name` creates a property on the instance. Unfortunately the value you've assigned to that property is `undefined` since the `alert()` function returns `undefined`. If you said `this.name = name` it would store the value that was in the function argument - that would be a more normal usage. Your `k` and `j` objects both have a `name` property with this syntax.

The second version, again with the `new person2()` syntax, will be creating objects that are instances of `person2`, however saying `person2.name` creates a property on the function itself. So that property is not accessible directly from the instances `k2` and `j2`, and every time you call `person2()` the `person2.name` property gets overwritten. There is no problem with having properties on functions like this in a general sense, but in this case it doesn't really make sense unless you really need to remember the name associated with the most recent invocation.

The third version, without using the `new` keyword, will simply assign the return value from `person3()` to the `k3` and `j3` variables, but since you don't explicitly return anything they'll end up as `undefined`. And the `person3.name` will work exactly the same way as for `person2`.

EDIT: Except, note that `name` has special meaning in the context of functions, so for the second and third options it won't behave quite the same as if you created a property with some other name that doesn't have special meaning, e.g., `myName`.